# Android failed to connect to ...with same ip

Tags: android, servlets, ip

I have coded a simple java server. And I use GET request. It works on The browser, but it throws an Exception when I use android network API.
There is err info:

> failed to connect to /192.168.1.103 (port 8077) after 6000ms

Someone said it happened because my phone's ip is not same as my server. But I am sure it is the same. My server and phone all under the same net environment.
There is my server's ip:
192.168.1.103

There is my Android code:

```
String httpUrl = "http://192.168.1.103:8077/education/servlet/LoginServlet ?" + "user_name=" + name + "&password=" + pass;//服务器地址


URL url = null;
HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
String result = "";
```

.......

It works with the same way. But now it always wrong!

Comment: When you say it works on the browser, is that on the phone or on your computer?

Comment: on the computer,it doesn't works on phone's browser but the computer

Comment: How do you know the computer's IP is accessible from the phone? Are they on the same netrowk? If you are unable to answer these questions, i would suggest you read about basic networking/routing.

Comment: My phone's network is same with the computer.They both under the a same Wifi.I also try to let my phone  connect the computer's wifi which is my server's ip.But it doesn't work.I think if my server and my client are the same network environment,my phone will connect the server.

Comment: You might need to try by disabling your computer's firewall temporairly. On window, the firewall blocks incomming trafic. Also, you might be binding to 127.0.0.1 and not the computer's external ip. Are you able to ping the computer's ip from the phone?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier Thank you very much! I have solved this problem by closing firewall yesterday.

Comment: Ok, maybe adding an exception would be a better solution (This would avoid compromising your computer)